# Trying to pass an array variable from asp to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

trying to pass an array variable to java
The following is not working, any idea why and how to make it work

**Code behind**

```
Public myArray (5) As String
myArray(1) = "A1"
myArray(2) = "A2"
myArray(3) = "A3"
myArray(4) = "A4"
myArray(5) = "A5"
```

**In asp**

```
<button type = "button" onclick="myJava('<%= myArray %>');">Search</button>
```

**In Javascript**

```
function myJava (myArray) {
   alert(myArray[1]); // expected answer is A1 but it is not
}
```

Comment: _"expected answer is A1 but it is not"_ what are you seeing instead? Not an asp guy, but the single quotes around your array would be causing you to pass a string, maybe try: `onclick="myJava(<%= myArray %>);"`

Comment: myArray[1] is giving y and myArray[2] is giving s, very strange

Comment: I have tried removing  single quotes it refused to execute the onclick

Comment: Hm, what does `alert(myArray)` show?

Comment: System.String[]

Comment: If it's returning `System.String[]`, then this is ASP.NET, not ASP. And it's Java**script**, not Java.

Comment: Also note that arrays start at `0`; you have declared a six-element array, and are simply ignoring the first element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly encode your array. Firstly, you need to convert it to a JSON string; then you need to encode that string as an HTML attribute value.

Add a reference to [the `Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). Add an `Imports` statement for the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace. Add a method to your code-behind to return the properly-encoded function call:

```
Public Function PassArrayToJavascript(ByVal functionName As String) As String
    Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myArray)
    Dim result As String = functionName + "(" + json + ");"
    Return System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(result)
End Function
```

Then update your markup to call this function:

```
<button type = "button" onclick="<%= PassArrayToJavascript("myFunction") %>">Search</button>
```